# LDAP missing attributes

Tags: java, ldap, missing-data

When I try to get all attributes of my LDAP InitialDirContext, some attributes are missing.

```java
_IDC = new javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext("...");
javax.naming.directory.DirContext dc = (javax.naming.directory.DirContext) _IDC.lookup("...");
javax.naming.NamingEnumeration<javax.naming.NameClassPair> ne = dc.list("");

if (ne.hasMore()) {
    javax.naming.directory.Attributes attributes = dc.getAttributes(ne.next().getName());
    javax.naming.NamingEnumeration<String> ids = attributes.getIDs();
    while (ids.hasMore()) {
        _People_attributes.add(ids.next()); //Put it in a List<String>
    }
}
```

I found : edupersonorgdn, edupersonorgunitdn ....
But when I display one line of a searched result, there is a composite attribute (supannetuinscription) :

```java
supannetuinscription=supannEtuInscription:  
[etab={UAI}0640251A][anneeinsc=2012][regimeinsc=I][cursusann={SUPANN}1][affect=33096]    
[diplome={SISE}8000100][libDiplome=C2i - niveau 1 spécialité C2i - niveau 1]  
[libDiplomeAbrev=C2i - niveau 1(X2I1299)][etape=FC2I1][libEtape=C2i -niveau 1]
```

Any idea ? Is that because of the composite attribute ?
If I can get it, can I get the "sub attributes" like etab, anneeinsc...

Thanks.

Comment: Is supannetuinscription an operational attribute or a regular user attribute?

Comment: There's nothing in JNDI that will handle a composite attribute. You may have to switch to another API.

Comment: @TerryGardner, I really don't know, sorry..

Comment: @EJP, thank you now what is the best solution for me to search in this composite attribute in JNDI ? String search ?